# How do LINQ queries update if variables they include are updated?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

So I know the classic example is something like

```
int pivot = 65; 
var socialSecurityDrawers = from person in People
                            where person.Age >= pivot
                            select person;

pivot = 70; 
// Since we raised the retirement age, socialSecurityDrawers has been re-filtered accordingly
```

But I'm confused at how the variable `pivot` in the query `from person in People where person.Age >= pivot select person` is updated. I understand that the query is thought of by the compiler as

```
var socialSecurityDrawers = People.Where(p => p.Age > pivot);
```

However, since pivot is an `int` and therefore a **value** type, I don't understand how passing in `pivot` into a lambda expression essentially makes it a reference to `pivot` unless there's some boxing that goes on. Is that what happens? If not, then this kinda reminds me of [hoisting](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp) in JavaScript and I'm wondering if that's a good analogy.

Comment: It's called a closure, and there is some compiler magic involved. Basically what's happening compiler will create a class to wrap around that `int` value and pass reference to that class into `Where` method as well as replace occurences of it in your method to point to a field in that class. That's why if you change it later it's updated in the closure too.

Comment: Hint: Imagine you have a class (reference type) instance and `int pivot` field inside.

Comment: The following post should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/852747/does-c-sharp-pass-by-value-to-lambdas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets see what happens. [The compiler generates](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#f:r/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoUlaIoYB0AwgPYA2lqAxsmORCMQOKoSoBOYtOe0eEjTpiAGUgBHHNgAOwAEaVeMWpQCGIEDFIwA3thhGY8pSoBu5MABMYAWQAUASn2Hj7iSgA8ABW4gmAD4TVHJZGhgAXhhOAHcYT2RffyDnHHd3SGQTMEts6IA2AFZ0jKM3MvN1LhguVBBgSnyYADMucnQQrgCIGEgQsJoKspHR91iAC25ULp7iAEEoGcDo2VzyZGGx7YyQVBp6WaZSsq3jNbyomAB2AAYTmABfbGe5RWVaVQ0tGD9upmwBncpg+fQg2UWMz0MCWyEwMD2cKeLyAA) the following display class:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass0_0
{
    public int pivot;
    internal bool <M>b__0(Person person)
    {
        return person.Age >= this.pivot;
    }
}
```

And turns your method into:

```
C.<>c__DisplayClass0_0 <>c__DisplayClass0_ = new C.<>c__DisplayClass0_0();
IEnumerable<Person> arg_1F_0 = new List<Person>();
<>c__DisplayClass0_.pivot = 65;
arg_1F_0.Where(new Func<Person, bool>(<>c__DisplayClass0_.<M>b__0));
<>c__DisplayClass0_.pivot = 70;
```

Thus, it actually updates the value *inside the display class*. When the `Enumerable.Where` is constructed, it is passed the delegate which resides in that same display class, which makes sure the value is updated once you decide to execute your query.